Using `opaque type` as a typeclass in Scala
Any idea why this does not compile: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/iPmLyim4Q8aQ2aMNIfj2gA
opaque type Global[Value] = Unit
object Global:
  def derived[Value]: Global[Value] = ()

case class Yo() derives Global


❗Playground.Global is not a class type

But this does: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/d148ISEcQ8Swu96lH6JMCw
case class Global[Value]()
object Global:
  def derived[Value]: Global[Value] = Global()

case class Yo() derives Global

?

Regarding minimizing the example: Note that the trait Dimensions is of no particular importance here, if one replaces Dimensions[Value] by Unit everywhere, it still results in the same behavior; Also, the object Dimensions: seems like a distraction, and can be removed without losing the essence.

Thanks, I edited with your suggestion @AndreyTyukin

https://github.com/scala/scala3/issues/19945 - see reply by Martin Odersky there

As @MartinHH mentioned in the comments, this is not supported as of today and an enhancement ticket is open.
Thanks
